# Rotate actions don't work in iPhone 5S and iPad Air, for cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Using `cocos2d-1.0.1`

Have

```
    [sprite runAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:10.0 angle:360]];
```

Your sprite rotates all nicely. Works fine on all devices and iOS versions.

... except iPhone 5S and iPad Air. If you do the above code, the rotation is super glitchy.

The only thing in common I see in those devices is the fact that they have some new processor thing.

What do I do? Any `Rotate` action is messed up on those devices.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it!

I digged into the implementation of `CCRotateBy` and `CCRotateTo`. Their `update` methods are like

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) t
{   
    [target_ setRotation: (startAngle_ +angle_ * t )];
}
```

But Xcode warns you that `target_` has multiple implementations of `setRotation`. If you cast it to `CCNode` it works!

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) t
{   
    [(CCNode*)target_ setRotation: (startAngle_ +angle_ * t )];
}
```

I don't know why does this problem manifest only on those devices, though.

Comment: a good solution, thank you. Have you got any troubles with audio, especially resuming audio? On the iPad Air background music doesn't resumed but on others devices all fine. I'm using SimpleAudioEngine

Comment: the issue was that need to been changed
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];  to
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];